# Rendering the wrath of a vengeful god

Tags: design

I'm planning on doing the [Indiana Jones Face Melting Scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YcR9k8o4I0w).
At time frame 1:08 of that clip, you can see arcs of energy going out from the Ark, devouring the Nazi soldiers. My current plan is to use the [transparent neck bracket with 2 studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=18986#T=C&C=12), then attaching transparent red or green bars to that to make the energy arcs. However, the arc is depicted as going out in a sort of cone or fan shape, rather then in straight lines.  Is there a way I can attach some bars to the back of a figure at an angle (33-45 degrees or so)?

Or is there another way altogether I can approach this?

Comment: I've also got some of the single neck brackets saved up. I can use those if it works better somehow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way you could achieve that is to use [Minifigure, Utensil Posing Stand, Bar with Hollow Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=65578#T=C) with the bracket you've mentioned. Not entirely sure of an exact angle, but it looks to be close to 45°/135° angle.

[image]